# Compiled dll for APC extension for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, apache, 64-bit, apc, windows-server

This might not be a programming question but I am posting it after long search  and confusion.

I have a dedicated server running Windows server 2008/64bit running Apache as a web server and using PHP 5.3.9

I am trying to install APC extension for Apache. From what I found on php.net I should use a V6 version because I am using Apache.

I searched everywhere to find APC for PHP 5.3 vc6 x64 and found nothing

This [comment](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-3-4-x64-64-bit-for-windows/#comment-7332) says that "it’s not possible to compile 64 bit PHP binaries with VC6 since it does not have 64 bit compiler" I don't know if that's true or just an assumption

Any help will be gladly appreciated/

Update, I cannot use VC9 as stated on windows.php.net

> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need to use the VC6 versions of PHP
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS you should use the VC9 versions of PHP
>
> VC6 Versions are compiled with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler
>
> VC9 Versions are compiled with the Visual Studio 2008 compiler and
>   have improvements in performance and stability. The VC9 versions
>   require you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x86) or the
>   Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x64) installed
>
> Do **NOT** use VC9 version with apache.org binaries
>
> VC9 versions of Apache can be fetched at Apache Lounge. We use their
>   binaries to build the Apache SAPIs.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I was given wrong information about the server configuration and settings. phpinfo() revealed the following:

```
Compiler        MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x86
```

So I used built VC9 and x86 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Try the VC9 DLL first. If you run into any real problems come back. VC6 is not explicitly needed for apache. You need to get the same VC version as the PHP binary.

Comment: Updated my question with a reference from php.net website stating why I cannot use VC9. Thanks

Comment: Which SAPI are you using with PHP?

Comment: Do you mean the Web Server to PHP interface ?

Comment: I found it's Apache 2.0 Handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to run PHP as an Apache module on my Windows development machine. However, as PHP has [stopped releasing VC6 binaries](http://windows.php.net/), I run the VC9 non theadsafe 32-bit versions as a FCGI module. There is plenty of documentation from both Apache and PHP on how to install these.

Then all you have to do is download the latest APC dll from [here](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc/file/details/apc-319-for-php-53-vc9-nts.html). Make sure you get the non-threadsafe version (nts), plonk it in your ext folder and just enable it like any other extension.

Edit: Didn't see that you wanted to run the 64-bit version. I haven't had a chance to try that out. However, if you are happy with running 32-bit versions of Apache and PHP, the above should work well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work probably cause it's 32-bit version. Thanks again for your advice

Comment: VC9 86x was exactly what I needed, please see the update to the question. Thanks so much